# How to link a function which is never referenced in C

Tags: c, linker

The linker's default behavior is to exclude all functions which is never referenced. However I want to include such a function for debugging purpose : when program runs abnormally, I can manually set PC to the address of this function and giving some information output.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Specify the object file containing the function on the linker's command line (or the compiler's command line).  The compiler links all object files specified, and libraries as required.  Or create `void dummy(void) { otherwise_unreferenced_function(void); }` in the file containing `main()` so there really is a reference to it, even though you never call `dummy()`.

Comment: MS link.exe has [`/INCLUDE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs.aspx) and GNU ld `-u` / `--undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The linker's default behavior is to exclude all functions which is never referenced.

That statement is false for all linkers I am familiar with: if you *explicitly* list the object file in which `foo()` is defined on the link line, then `foo()` is *always* included in the executable or shared library being linked (well, except when you specify `--function-sections -Wl,--gc-sections` on the link line).

It is true that if `foo()` is defined in an object file, and that object file is in an *archive* library, and that object file does not satisfy any references to any symbols it defines coming from other files already being used in the link, *then* that object file will not be pulled into the link.

The solution then is to either

- list `foo.o` explicitly on the link line, or
- use `-Wl,--whole-archive -lfoo -Wl,--no-whole-archive` (or equivalent flags for your linker, if it has them), or
- add `-u foo` to force `foo.o` to be pulled into the link.

Answer (score 0):

First create an object file of that c file which contains the function.

```
gcc <Yourfile_Name>.c -o functions.o
```

And use ld to  create the executable. I don't know how to do this with Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler.